# Next tag badge progress is not aligned properly in mobile web

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, mobile-web, tag-badges

The next tag badge in the user profile page (activity tab) is not aligned properly:

> [image: tag badge]

I think it should be centered horizontally on the page.